# PDF digital signature on page icon indicating signature validity

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

I am generating digital signatures for PDF using iText 5.5.9 and the example `C2_01_SignHelloWorld.java` given at [digital signature white paper examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security/digital-signatures-white-paper/digital-signatures-chapter-2).

I am getting plain digital signature appearance.  What I need is a digital signature that appears with an icon that indicates its verification status like the yellow question mark in this example:

[image: pdf signature with visible verification indicator]

This yellow question mark changes to a red cross or a green tick depending on whether the signature was verified or not.

I have searched for this for the past two days and the only difference I see is that the digital certificate that I am using is self signed whereas the digital certificate used in the reference PDF is issued by a vendor who is in Adobe Approved Trust List.  But before I make that purchase, I would like to know if I am missing out something obvious.

Comment: Such a signature would be in violation with the PAdES standard. Tell whoever asked you to implement this to read PAdES.

Comment: The verification status is something that only the client that opens your file can finally tell, right? So that is the place where a check or a cross could be added in some way or another.

Comment: The icons appear to be part of the signature box.  in other readers like preview in mac os, only the yellow question mark appears.  in adobe reader dc however it displays a dialog about downloading certificates and the yellow question mark changes to a green tick.

Comment: The use of these on-page indicators of signature validity has been deprecated a long time ago. If i recall correctly, even before pdf became an ISO standard, when it still was an adobe controlled format. Adobe Reader only supports this for backward compatibility. If you take current standards like PAdES into account, such indications inside the document are not allowed anymore. That been said, you can use / tweak itext to create such signatures but they will start out with questionable legal value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pdf Signature Validity Check Mark Not Visible on Acrobat Reader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755989/pdf-signature-validity-check-mark-not-visible-on-acrobat-reader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this kind of icon to appear, set two additional properties in the PdfSignatureAppearance object.

Follow along from the [`Signatures.java` example](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/book/raw/master/src/part3/chapter12/Signatures.java) in Chapter 12 of the iText in Action book, and modify according to this snippet.

```
// appearance
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
// insert the next two lines
appearance.setAcro6Layers(false);
appearance.setLayer4Text(PdfSignatureAppearance.questionMark);
```

In case you are working with `iTextSharp`, these are properties, so you will have to do:

```
appearance.Acro6Layers = false;
appearance.Layer4Text = PdfSignatureAppearance.questionMark;
```

Comment: Please be aware that support for these has been deprecated a long time ago. You set `Acro6Layers = false` because the layers you use were the technology of Adobe Acrobat before version 6, i.e. ancient. The ISO standard does not know such "layers" at all, and current standards like PAdES even forbid such on-page indicators of signature validity.

Comment: shockingly enough this is very much in use by indian government agencies including income tax when sending pdf receipts.  because of this precedent, the client insisted on this feature.  when we showed the client the standards and this post and the comment by Bruno Lowagie the CREATOR OF ITEXT library, the client said bluntly "will you do this, or should I go elsewhere?".

Comment: ROTFL... OK, I see, in that case you simply do what the customer insists on. If I were you, I'd merely make sure the customer has provably been informed about the implications.